# Add normal table tag CSS to tabulator table

Tags: css, tabulator, custom-formatting

I have few css files that has classes to be added for table tags like `<table>`, `<th>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`. I have created a table using tabulator but it gets rendered using  tags. Is there a way I can add my custom CSS to tabulator div tag based table??

Answer (score 1):

Tabulator is far more advanced than a standard HTML table, so there is no way that it can be built using `table` tags. Instead it is built using a series of div's with classes that define their purpose and styling.

The [Styling Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/style#css) includes a full list of classes used for the table.

So it is simply a matter of switching out your tags in your CSS for classes.

So for example, this:

```css
table{
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

Would become:

```css
.tabulator{
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

The following are a list of the classes corresponding to a html table:

- `table` - .tabulator
- `tr` - .tabulator-row
- `td` - .tabulator-cell
- `th` - .tabulator-col